# Simple differential equation with partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule

> Assume that f satisfies the differential equation $\frac{∂f}{∂x} = 3
> > \frac{∂f}{∂y}$ in the entire plane. Show that f is constant on every
> line that is parallel with the line $3x + y = 1$.

I feel like in order to show that it is constant, I need show that that partial derivatives are $0$ for lines parallel with the line. But the problem I don't know how to go about doing it, I need a hint.

Comment: What means 'throughout the planet' ?

Comment: I've edited it now and hopefully it makes sense now.

Comment: Directions : You can first write the general form of all plane parallel to yours. Then express y in a function of x for each of these plane. Then calculating the differential of $f$ on this plane (using chain rule).